# Once opened and n-times written or n-times open but one time written per openning?

Tags: python, file, memory, file-io, time-complexity

So the problem is - which case to use? I got list of urls and got some magic function get_text_from_url - and I have to write this into the file with given filename - simply as can be, but which case of this two is better than another and why? 

The priority in this case is time and memory - not readability (sorry, Python).

And, of course, any other versions are welcome.

First:

```
def create_text(filename):        
    delete_current_text(filename)
    urllist = get_urls()
    for url in urllist:
        with open(filename, "a") as file:
             print >>file, get_text_from_url(url)
```

Second:

```
def create_text(filename):        
    urllist = get_urls()
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
         for url in urllist:
             print >>file, get_text_from_url(url)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example would be better, since open/close operation on files has significant overhead, and the latter only did it once.

However, it should be even better if you store the result (if get_text_from_url won't return a too big content), like this:

```
def create_text(filename):
    urllist = get_urls()
    result = map(get_text_from_url, urllist)
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        file.write("\n".join(result))
```

So there's only one write, and only blocks the file for a short period of time (assuming that get_text_from_url will do web request, which costs much longer time than local file writes).

Comment: Sorry, but this is for machine learning purposes, so that I can't map it. In my case it's something like up to 10 Mb, but it's possible to use my code for bigger sizes, so I want to keep this code working for big cases.

Comment: Okay. So if memory usage is the issue, I'd say stick with the second example.

Answer (score 1):

The I/O will be faster if you open the file, do the writes, then close it when you're done. In reality, you're choosing between "open once, write n", and "open n, write n" (not "open n, write once" as you stated). With the latter option, you're only doing one write per open, but you're still doing n writes total.

Comment: I've editted questions name. So, it will be better if I open once? I'm asking just to clearify. But how it will work inside - does openning of file stores something in memory, or will is there some difference in IO working with 'w' or 'a' options? I understand the difference between them, but does IO works differently in meaning of time and memory?

Comment: @htzfun usually we assume that memory usage is cheaper than I/O cost like read/write files. But if it's not the case (like if the data to write is just too big), consider streaming the writes instead.

Comment: @htzfun Opening the file will result in your program holding a file descriptor to it in memory. This is an insignificant amount of memory, though, and you shouldn't worry about it when considering time/speed constraints. Really, the memory cost between your two proposed approaches isn't much different at all. The major difference between the two is that the n-open approach will be much slower, because opening/closing files is slow. You can easily test both approaches and compare their speed to see for yourself.